# How can I get back my desktop? the left and top panels

Tags: 12.10, ati, panel, radeon

I installed the Ubuntu 12.10 and the driver for ATI Radeon HD 4330 (AMD Catalyst™ 12.6 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver) and the latest updates. After the restart now I can see only the desktop background and nothing more. No left or top panels. The resolution changed to 1024X768 and the graphic changed to: VESA:M92.

What happened? Is there something wrong with the driver? How can I solve this?

I'm a beginner, please answer according to this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove ATI drivers from your system:

Access to your terminal:

```
ctr+alt+F3
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
```

Then, remove your xorg.conf:

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Re-configure Xorg:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Then, reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

**If this doesn't work, try to re-install XORG:**

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
```

Re-configure Xorg:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Then, reboot again:

```
sudo reboot
```